# How do I remap a Python Pandas Series of ints to 0,1,2,3,4 based on their order from smallest to largest?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, series

I would like to remap a Python Pandas Series of ints to 0,1,2,3,4,... based on their order from smallest to largest. Equal ints should be mapped to the same int.

For example, if I have a pandas Series `[1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 12, 18, 18]`, I would like it mapped to `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]`. Basically it's like squishing the ints so that they're next to each other.

I've tried converting to a standard list and using a naive implementation, but wondering if there's a more idiomatic way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas-categorical):

```py
s = pd.Series([1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 12, 18, 18])

print(pd.Categorical(s).codes)
```

Prints:

```
[0 0 1 1 2 3 4 4]
```

Comment: I was going to post an alternative to `rank` with `Categorical`. Nice point :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with dense method:

```
>>> sr.rank(method='dense').sub(1).astype(int)
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    4
dtype: int64
```

Or [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
>>> pd.factorize(sr)[0]
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4])
```

Or [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
>>> np.unique(sr, return_inverse=True)[1]
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4])
```

There are lots of ways to do this with Pandas/Numpy including with `Categorical` posted by @AndrejKesely.